Unable to sent records to Db from kafka topic using Microsoft sql server sink connector
Summary: I need to send records to kafka topic and using microsoft sql server sink connector have to fetch the record from topic and send to database.
**
Approaches i tried for sending records to topic.**
1)Manual Approach (Produce a message button)
2)Rest api (postman)
3)Java producer application (using Ide)
4)Boomi process
**
Concern:**

Whenever i produce records manually (in confluent cloud produce message button) it sent to topic and mssql sink connector will processed the record and sent to db -→ This case is succeed

But if i send with the help of 3rd parties like Boomi, Postman, Java application ==> Records sent to topic but the mssql sink connector will push the records into DLQ, it wont sent to Db.
This is the error i noticed in DLQ message.
This is the schema i added for the topic


[   {     "key": "__connect.errors.topic",     "value": "sample_data_test"   },   {     "key": "__connect.errors.partition",     "value": "5"   },   {     "key": "__connect.errors.offset",     "value": "12"   },   {     "key": "__connect.errors.connector.name",     "value": "lcc-vk28vj"   },   {     "key": "__connect.errors.task.id",     "value": "0"   },   {     "key": "__connect.errors.stage",     "value": "VALUE_CONVERTER"   },   {     "key": "__connect.errors.class.name",     "value": "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter"   },   {     "key": "__connect.errors.exception.class.name",     "value": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException"   },   {     "key": "__connect.errors.exception.message",     "value": "Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic sample_data_test: "   },   {     "key": "__connect.errors.exception.stacktrace",     "value": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: **Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic sample_data_test:** \n\tat io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:144)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$5(WorkerSinkTask.java:546)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:217)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:254)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:546)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:521)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:347)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:247)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:216)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:247)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:302)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$7(Plugins.java:339)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing JSON message for id -1\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:238)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:315)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(JsonSchemaConverter.java:193)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:127)\n\t... 17 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.getByteBuffer(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:638)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:129)\n\t... 20 more\n"   } ]


So, In Java producer application what i have done is before sending message to topic i did the serialization also.

**1)Is there any Limitation for mssql sink connector (while sending records through 3rd parties)?
2)Is there any other approach?**
(Whenever i send records to kafka topic via boomi process using kafka connector, restapi, or java producer application)Mssql sink connector should process the record and send to db.
Note: By using the above approaches data sent to topic but mssql sink can't processed these records.

JsonschemaConverter isn't the same as JSONConverter. You cannot add a schema after the data is already produced to the topic; it needs to be serialized with JsonschemaSerializer as it's written to the topic. Please show your producer code as a [mcve]


Error deserializing JSON message for id -1

This message typically means you've not properly serialized your data to include any schema. It's a producer issue  not a sink issue.
JDBC sink connector always requires some schema on the data. Sending plaintext JSON will have no schema.
I don't use Confluent Cloud UI, but my understanding is that you cannot control the serialization in it; it's just sending text and never referencing any schemas while using it to produce.
Similarly, Boomi may not fully support Confluent serialization methods, such as Jsonschema

Is there any reference guide to send records to kafka topic via third parties and using microsoft sql server sink connector to send those records to database?

I'm sure there are, but the configuration documentation itself should always be referred to, rather than potentially outdated blog posts. I'm not familiar with Boomi
